# Андроид. Sugar ORM ошибка при добавлении в БД

Tags: android, база-данных, orm

Решил попробовать использовать Sugar ORM вместо SQLite, но у меня постоянно  вылетает ошибка, не могу понять что делаю не так. Код уже полностью скопировал с сайта
http://www.fandroid.info/orm-dlya-uproshheniya-raboty-s-sqlite-v-android-na-primere-sugar-orm/

Может кто разбирается в ORM на Android. Буду благодарен.

Исходник

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.artsait.orm">

<application
    ...
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
    <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugar_example.db"/>
    <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1"/>
    <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="net.artsait.orm"/>
    <activity
        ...>
        <intent-filter>
            ...
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

content_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="net.artsait.orm.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Name"></EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Email"></EditText>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Read"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear"></Button>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

Contact.java

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;

public class Contact extends SugarRecord{

    String name;
    String mail;

    public Contact() {
    }

    public Contact(String mail, String name) {
        this.mail = mail;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", mail='" + mail + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {

    // переменные для кнопок и текста
    Button btnAdd, btnRead, btnClear;
    EditText etName, etEmail;
    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // связывем с лояутом
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
        btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        // обработчик нажатия
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRead.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String mail = etEmail.getText().toString();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAdd:
                Contact contact = new Contact(mail, name);
                contact.save();
                break;

            case R.id.btnRead:
                List<Contact> allContacts = Contact.listAll(Contact.class);
                textView.setText(allContacts.toString());
                break;

            case R.id.btnClear:
                Contact.deleteAll(Contact.class);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Логи:

```
09-07 13:48:58.694 21363-21363/net.artsait.orm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: net.artsait.orm, PID: 21363
                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: CONTACT (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO CONTACT(ID,NAME,MAIL) VALUES (?,?,?)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                     at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:280)
                                                                     at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:416)
                                                                     at net.artsait.orm.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-07 13:49:02.117 21363-21363/net.artsait.orm I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21363 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `CONTACT` таблица не найдена

Comment: А в чем может быть проблема, вроде все верно прописал?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было просто поменять версию БД на 3
Почему так, не знаю